# align navigation and content without using a table html5

Tags: css, html

[image]I'm trying to get the title hot rods to line up with the navigation, and the photo to float right and line up with the text content below it as well as the title and navigation to the left of it. I also need to get the navigation bar to extend the length of the photo until the text content. (as shown in the picture)

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ysette Ortiz – Assignment 01</title>
  <link href="rod_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <div id="body">
  <body>
  </br>
  <div id="container">
  <div id="nav">

  <nav>
  <div id="h1">
  <h1> HOT RODS! </h1>
  </div>
  <ol>

     <li>Home</li>
     <li>Rods</li>
     <li>Lifestyle</li>

  </ol>
  <div id="image"><img src="Images/duece.jpg" width="500" height="323" alt=""/></div>
</nav>

 </div>
<div id="Content"><p>Hot rods are typically American cars with large engines modified for linear speed. The origin of the term "hot rod" is unclear. One explanation is that the term is a contraction of "hot roadster," meaning a roadster that was modified for speed. Another explanation is that the mufflers were exposed and thus there was a "hot rod" or hot muffler neck when the vehicle was running. Open roadsters were the cars of choice to modify because they were light. Hot Rod may also refer to the connecting rods, cam, or pushrods inside the engine or to the exposed frame rails of such an automobile. To me, the American hot rod is a thing of beauty created by artisans who use steel, rubber, and glass as their canvas.
</p>
</div>
</div>
</br></br></br></br></br></br>
</body>

</html>

//css------>
@charset "UTF-8";
#body{ background-image:url(Images/road_and_mountain.jpg);
background-size:cover;
    }
#container {
    width: 804px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#nav ul, li{ 
    font:Verdana;
    width: 200px;
    font-size:1.3em;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}
#h1{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
    width: 200px;
    }
#Content{ 
    width:804px;
    font:times new roman;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;


    }
#image container{
    width:604px;
    float:right;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add an image of what exactly you want?

Comment: @Junaid I have added a picture for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep them aligned in same line then you should give all their blocks same display i.e. Display: inline-block. Inline block will align all your elements in single line. 
You can also add different width to them if you wish to do that.
Try this.

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ysette Ortiz ? Assignment 01</title>
  <link href="rod_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <div id="body">
  <body>
  </br>
  <div id="container">
  <div id="nav">

  <nav>
  <div id="h1" style = "display:inline-block">
  <h1> HOT RODS! </h1>
  </div>
  <ol style = "display:inline-block">

     <li style = "display:inline-block">Home</li>
     <li style = "display:inline-block">Rods</li>
     <li style = "display:inline-block">Lifestyle</li>

  </ol>
  <div style = "display:inline-block" id="image"><img src="Images/duece.jpg" width="500" height="323" alt=""/></div>
</nav>

 </div>
<div id="Content"><p>Hot rods are typically American cars with large engines modified for linear speed. The origin of the term "hot rod" is unclear. One explanation is that the term is a contraction of "hot roadster," meaning a roadster that was modified for speed. Another explanation is that the mufflers were exposed and thus there was a "hot rod" or hot muffler neck when the vehicle was running. Open roadsters were the cars of choice to modify because they were light. Hot Rod may also refer to the connecting rods, cam, or pushrods inside the engine or to the exposed frame rails of such an automobile. To me, the American hot rod is a thing of beauty created by artisans who use steel, rubber, and glass as their canvas.
</p>
</div>
</div>
</br></br></br></br></br></br>
</body>

</html>
```